# How do I activate python virtual environment from a different repo?

Tags: python, django

So am working in a group project, we are using python and of the code is on GitHub. My question is how do I activate the virtual environment? Do I make one on my own using the "python virtual -m venv env" or the one that's on the repo, if there is such a thing. Thanks

Comment: Virtual environments do not belong in a code repository. Everyone should have it's own, which *can* be based on a `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

virtual env is used to make your original env clean. you can `pip install virtualenv` and then create a virtual env like `virtualenv /path/to/folder` then use `source /path/to/folder/bin/activate` to activate the env. then you can do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install dependencies into the env. then everything will be installed into /path/to/folder/lib

alteratively, you can use `/path/to/folder/bin/pip install` or `/path/to/folder/bin/python` without activating the env.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll want to create your own with something like: `python -m venv venv`. The final argument specifies where your environment will live; you could put it anywhere you like. I often have a `venv` folder in Python projects, and just .gitignore it.

After you have the environment, you can activate it. On Linux: `source venv/bin/activate`. Once activated, any packages you install will go into it; you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt` for instance.